# Failed resolution of: Lcom/vungle/publisher/FullScreenAdActivity from inside codename one app

Tags: java, android, codenameone

I got the native Android test app from AerServ working fine with Vungle. I am now trying to build a lib for codenameone to support AerServ and in turn vungle, but I'm getting:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/vungle/publisher/FullScreenAdActivity;`

I have looked a lot on the net and it seems to be something weird from looking at this link https://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/51268-vungle-ads-do-not-initialise-since-build-20142429-error-shows-up-in-app/

Could anyone give me some suggestions for why that class isn't found at run-time? Despite compiling and being imported fine.. All the other classes seem to work, I have the code below also which reports if classes are found and only the FullScreenAdActivity appears not to be found so far. I'm actually using the AerServ SDK but it I think it is Vungle related.

My code which reports what classes can be found:

```
isClass("com.aerserv.sdk.view.ASVastInterstitialActivity"); //FINE
    isClass("com.vungle.publisher.AdConfig"); //FINE
    isClass("com.vungle.publisher.FullScreenAdActivity");//NOT FOUND
    isClass("com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyFullscreen");//FINE


String classInfo="";
//for verfiying the libs exist
public boolean isClass(String className) {
try  {
    _("checking existance of class: "+className);
    Class.forName(className);
    _("Class found OK.");

    classInfo+=className+" OK\n";
    return true;
}  catch (final ClassNotFoundException e) {
    _("CLASS NOT FOUND. -> "+className);
    classInfo+=className+" BAD\n";
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It turned out the vungle jar inside aerserv sdk was old I grabbed new ones from their SDK and it worked! Ive packaged this up in a lib to help others, still implementing iOS as we speak https://github.com/amiga/aerserv-codenameone and also a testbed app containing the lib if you prefer the easy life (I do) https://github.com/amiga/aerserv-codenameone-testbed